# Error handling for adbannerview effect App Store review?

Tags: ios, iad, adbannerview

I have just submitted my iOS 8 app. In my storyboard, I have a `AdBannerView` at the bottom. I implemented the delegate and ***only*** implemented:

```
- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error
{
NSLog(@"Failed to retrieve ad");
}
```

I read in some forums where people tell me Apple will reject your app if you don't hide your `AdBannerView` when it fails.

What is the proper and conventional way to handle an ad failure? Should I replace the banner with another view?

Comment: I don't know if they actually reject apps that don't handle missing ads, but your app should definitely hide the banner when no ad is available (which happens quite often), no point in having a non useful view on the screen when it has no function.

Comment: Sudha, according to my knowledge it will not create any problem. I was working in an advertizer company and i have submitted apps with such methods succesfully till ios 6... Dont know if they have changed any policy. And yes when no ad is there you should hide the Adview.

Comment: Best practice is to use the space freed up by not having a banner. It's also a good idea to use more than 1 ad provider, so if you receive an ad error then you can try and load, for example, an AdMob banner instead.